# Kde: how to bind permanently an application to a desktop/activity?

Tags: kde, window-manager, desktop, desktop-environment, kde-activities

Im pretty new to Kde 4.8 and I can not figure out how to get this behaviour that I used to have in Gnome:

1. Desktop 1: developer/misc (browser, editor/ide, diff, etc..)
2. Desktop 2: virtual machines (vbox)
3. Desktop 3: graphic (gimp, inkscape, phatch)
4. Desktop 4: file management (ftp, ssh, etc..)

In gnome is possible to configure the windows to **always** appear in a specific desktop, and this is what I want to achieve in Kde.

I googled around so much, and looks like activities can't do that (yet), becose using the window's menu only works for the current session, and get lost after reboot.

By the way, I suppose that activities *can* do that, becose in the default activities that come with Kde 4.8 Gimp used to show only in the *photo* activity (I gave a look to the activity configuration but I didn't find anything about this behavior).

Onestly, my goal is to obtain this scenario, if it is not possible with activities but with desktops, for me is ok.

So, any idea on how to obtain this behavior in Kde 4.8?

I already read [this similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6623/how-do-i-associate-applications-with-kde-activities), but im looking for a *permanent* solution.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This (and much much more) can be done in advanced settings of KDE's window manager KWin. You can get to it if you right click on window titlebar and select Advanced > Special Application Settings (or Special Window Settings if you would like to apply only to specific window and not all windows of this app). Then on the Size and Position tab you can force it to open on specific virtual desktop or in specific activity (for activities you need KDE software compilation version 4.9, if I remember correctly).

Comment: this only works on kde windows.  for apps that don't go through kde, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

For 4.13.3, you right click on the window title bar and select More Actions -> Special Application Settings. This will open up a dialog with the tab "Size & Position". There will be a check box "Activity" with options to restrict the window to an activity.

Answer (score 0):

I recently upgraded to Kubuntu 22.04 and found that this procedure, which I've been using for many years, has been changed.

To make this happen now, I've opened "Special Window [or Application] Settings" and I get a small pop-up window with only a few options. However, down in the lower left corner is a button to "+ Add Property..." On clicking that, I see all the options I used to find more directly. When I click on one of them ("Initial Placement" for example) it disappears from this list and is added to the previous pop-up, where I can make the same adjustments as in the old method.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).